# Should I use a specific patch to upgrade ArcGis Server from 10.2 to 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, installation

http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/list?productid=66&productVersions=10.2.2&categoryTypes=8 Here I have fouund a list of patches and service packs. First of all whats the difference between patches and Service Packs. 
Does any patch of 10.2.2 performs the upgrade, or I have to install all the patches ?

Comment: generally speaking a patch fixes a specific or set of specific issues. a service pack rolls up all patches and bug fixes into one install.  I suggest the service pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10.2.2 release is a full install, not just a service pack (it need not be applied on top of 10.2 or 10.2.1; it should apply over an existing install, though you generally want to be extra-rigorous about your backups, just in case there are issues).

I'd recommend applying the 10.2.2 release, *then* **all** the relevant patches in chronological order (reverse of the order in the link you provided). By my count, 19 patches have been released:

1. ArcGIS 10.2 - 10.2.2 for Desktop Print Dialog Hang Patch
2. ArcGIS 10.2.2 for (Desktop/Engine/Server) Oracle Geodatabase Object Schema Update and Editing Patch
3. ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop Non-textured Multipatch Transparency Patch
4. ArcGIS 10.2.2 for (Desktop, Engine, Server) Update GeoPackage Support for the OGC Standard Version 1
5. ArcGIS 10.2.2 Workflow Manager for Desktop Multi Layer Groupings and TOC Refresh Patch
6. ArcGIS 10.2.2 for (Desktop, Engine, Server) Spatial Reference Consistency Patch
7. ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 - 10.2.2 for (Desktop, Engine, Server) OpenSSL Update Patch
8. ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 QIP – 10.2.2 (Desktop, Engine, Server) Tracking Layers Numeric NULL Values Patch
9. ArcGIS 10.2.2 Data Reviewer Patch 1
10. ArcGIS 10.2 – 10.2.2 for Desktop Digital Globe GeoEye Metadata/Product Layout Patch
11. ArcGIS 10.2.2 for (Desktop, Engine, Server) Set Shapefile Default Code Page Patch
12. ArcGIS 10 SP5 – 10.2.2 for (Desktop, Engine, Server) PDF Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere Patch
13. ArcGIS 10.2.1 & 10.2.2 for Desktop Hydrology Tools Ready-to-use-Services Patch
14. ArcGIS 10.2.2 for (Desktop, Engine, Server) Geodatabase and Feature Service Sync Optimization Patch
15. ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop Parcel Fabric General Maintenance Patch
16. ArcGIS 10.2.2 (Desktop, Engine, Server) Geographic or Datum Transformation Patch
17. ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 QIP, 10.2.1, and 10.2.2 for Server Security (August 2014) Patch
18. ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Server Patch - View Map and Image Services in the ArcGIS Online Scene Viewer
19. ArcGIS 'Oracle Critical Patch Update - October 2014' Connection Issue Patch

You can skip those that don't apply to your deployment, though if you change the deployment to need something, you may need to reapply the full cascade.